# Как конвертировать в обучную дату по нужному часовому поясу?

Tags: javascript

есть запись в MongoDB, которая формируется автоматически через Date.now и выглядит следующим обрзом
*2021-02-02T05:05:38.757+00:00.* Подскажите пожалуйста как пренести в нужный часовой пояс ибо при создании указывается время как в Германии + привезти к нормальному виду. В идеале **02.02.2021 05:05**

Спасибо

Comment: А «нужный часовой пояс» - это какой?)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Конечно если возможно что бы определялся в зависимости от пользователя. Но если нет можно МСК

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621426/convert-javascript-date-from-one-timezone-to-the-other